# How to determine memory usage for each job

Tags: sql-server

I have lots of jobs scheduled on my sql server, I want to find the jobs taking maximin time.

Comment: Repeating your title doesn't ask a question.What do you mean by a "job", an agent Job? A Batch, statement? User? (Application?) What have you tried and researched to answer this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script will show you your SQL Server Agent jobs ordered by the longest running.

```
SELECT      j.name,
            j.description,
            h.step_id,
            h.step_name,
            msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date,run_time) AS RunDate,
            run_duration,
            run_status
FROM        msdb..sysjobhistory h
            JOIN msdb..sysjobs j
                ON h.job_id = j.job_id
WHERE       enabled = 1 AND
            step_id = 1 
ORDER BY    run_duration DESC
```

Comment: thanks for the answer this is what I am looking for, can you also modify the query so that it will also return memory consumption in MB for each job?

Comment: I don't know that this is easily possible you could use perfmon and the perfmon counter DMVs but you would have to do that in realtime. msdb does not log this stuff